# How to make multiple senders send email in laravel

Tags: laravel-7

I create a simple application to manage follow-up students. I want to send an email from the sender address who is sending an email when they comment on a student. Why when I send an email I can get only address sender that I config in .eve file whenever I try to change an email in method from().

This my EmailController

```
public function htmlEmail()
{
    $data = [
        'name'      => 'virak',
        'message'   => 'The life of brian',
        'subject'   => 'Laravel Plain Email',
        'from'      => 'viraktestemail44@gmail.com',// I try to change email here but no 
                                                       result when I change.
        'from_name' => 'Laravel HTML Email',
    ];

    Mail::to('virakcambodia44@gmail.com', 'Virak')->send(new HTMLMail($data));

    return "HTML Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
}
```

This my mailable.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class HTMLMail extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $data;

public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->from($this->data['from'], $this->data['from_name'])
        ->subject($this->data['subject'])
        ->view('emails.html');
}
}
```

This my wep.php

```
Route::get('/html-email',[
'uses' => 'EmailController@htmlEmail',
]);
```

This my .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=virak.ran44@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=12345678
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=virak.ran44@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Swift Mailer
For This it is Great and quick Result

https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html

I have Dummy code in My Project Used Previously
:

// Create the Transport

```
        $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport($mail_details->outgoing_server,$mail_details->outgoing_server_port,$outgoing_encryption))
          ->setUsername($mail_details->mail_email_address)
          ->setPassword($mail_details->mail_email_password)
          ;

        /*
        You could alternatively use a different transport such as Sendmail:

        // Sendmail
        $transport = new Swift_SendmailTransport('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');
        */

        // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
        $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

        // Create a message
        $message = (new Swift_Message($subject))
          ->setFrom([$mail_details->mail_email_address => $mail_details->mail_username])
          ->setTo($toemail)
          ->setCc($tocc)
          ->setBcc($tobcc)
          ->setBody($message,'text/html');


          if (Input::hasFile('attachments')) {


          $attachments = Input::file('attachments');

          foreach ($attachments as $attachments_key => $attachments_data) 
          {
            $destinationPath = 'uploads/emails-saved/';  
            $attachments_name = $attachments_data->getClientOriginalName();
            $test=$attachments_data->move($destinationPath,$attachments_name);
            $file = public_path().'/uploads/emails-saved/'. $attachments_name;

            $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($file)->setFilename($attachments_name));

          }


          }


        // Send the message
        $result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: This won't work using the gmail mailserver. Google will simply reject the request. The mailserver where the website sits may allow it, technically. It's a legal problem really. You are not allowed to send emails FROM other people. This practice could bring @Virak into trouble. Most hosting services won't even allow it.